# replacement for Selenium tool in Auto web form filling

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am doing auto web form filling using Selenium and I am looking for replacement for the selenium. Please suggest me the alternate for selenium.

here is the code for selenium

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;


public class Googletest {
private Selenium selenium;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "https://www.gmail.com/");
    selenium.start();
}

@Test
public void testGoogletest() throws Exception {
selenium.open("/");
selenium.type("//div[@class='email-div']/input", "rashmiujire13@gmail.com");
selenium.type("//div[@class='passwd-div']/input", "xxxxxx");


selenium.click("signIn");
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
selenium.stop();
}
}
```

Comment: I know you are screwed but don't ask for the code here.. no one will code for you..

Comment: sorry i edited my question actually i need alternate tool instead of selenium

Comment: I used selenium and works fine for me. What issue you are facing while using selenium?

Comment: Not any issue but i want to know new tool

Comment: I did the same but couldn't find better replacement..

Comment: oh. can you please check that for me.

Comment: If nothing is wrong with Selenium, why are you finding a replacement? Don't fix what isn't broken. On the other hand, you ought to be using Selenium WebDriver as opposed to Selenium RC.

Answer (score 1):

[WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

Selenium - RC is deprecated, and has no further development going on.